# How to fix This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: laravel, heroku

I've just deployed an app on heroku and it's not rendering as expected. After checking the console I'm getting the below error. How do i fix this?

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://photography-web-by-alphy.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://photography-web-by-alphy.herokuapp.com/css/style.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I used secure asset helper function.
   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ secure_asset('css/style.css') }}">`
2. I updated the APP_URL in the .env file from http to https. Then in the Config Vars on heroku I added the KEY to APP_URL and the value I provided the same value of the APP_URL from the .env then redeployed app and it now worked fine with no error!

Answer (score 1):

When your doc is served as HTTPS, other resources must be called as HTTPS as well, such as css, js images and etc.

So, just try import that css with https://... and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. I'm I supposed to change how I'm fetching the styles? If so, how I'm I supposed to change this  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">

Comment: So, check if in your .env file the APP_URL variable is set as http or https

Comment: I fixed it thank you!

1. I used secure asset helper function.
```<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ secure_asset('css/style.css') }}">```

2. I updated the APP_URL in the .env file from http to https. Then in the Config Vars on heroku I added the KEY to APP_URL and the value I provided the same value of the APP_URL from the .env then redeployed app and it now worked fine with no error!

Comment: Great. Check my answer as correct if it helped you, please.

Comment: Just changing http to https did not work, I had to update Config Vars on heroku which didn't work also until I added the secure_asset helper function so I'm not sure if I should check yours or mine that I've provided above. Perhaps you may advice which one should I check that will someone looking at this in the future!

Answer (score 1):

To force HTTPS in Laravel you should add inside App\Providers\AppServiceProvider:

```
public function register()
    {
    if(config('app.env') === 'production') {
            $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true); 
    }
}
```

NOTE in your .env change APP_ENV=local to APP_ENV=production

Answer (score 0):

To force HTTPS in Laravel you should add inside `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`:

```php
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if (!App::environment([
            'local',
            'testing',
        ])) {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your environment? Could you try it without the if? Could you send your AppServiceProvider.php? And whats your Heroku Url?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use asset, and then no protocol will be forced

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Alternatively, and preferably, configure your Trusted Proxy settings to detect the required protocol.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

Answer (score 0):

Just I changed from http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap . . .
to https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap . . .

Issue resolved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).